# Angular 6 + material 2 on IE 11(edge) is very slow when entering text by keyboard

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, angular-material2

We are facing a very weird issue only on Internet Explorer 11.  When entering text in text boxes or text areas using the keyboard, the cursor is delaying and character refresh is very slow.

Angular 6 + Material 2

We enabled production mode but still no luck.  Uncommented and added all poly-fills, still no luck.

**Note** : Chrome and Firefox are working fine.

Comment: The [demos](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) work fine for me in IE11.

Comment: Try to clear IE cache or close other window and re-open IE browser to test your code. Also, you could test your code on another computer.

Comment: Got the same problem with angular6+ and Edge (without material) in some apps. I got no idea (yet) to the cause.